# Deploy VM from template and set VM and DNS name

Tags: vmware, pyvmomi

I’m using pyVmomi to deploy a VM from a template on vSphere,
this woks ok, the new VM get the name I sent as parameter but I want that the DNS name \ hostname will be same as VM.
Is there a way to set the hostname when doing the actual clone ?
If not how can I do that after the new VM was created ?

Here is part of the code I'm using:

```
# RelocateSpec
relospec = vim.vm.RelocateSpec()
relospec.datastore = datastore
relospec.pool = resource_pool

# ConfigSpec
configSpec = vim.vm.ConfigSpec()
configSpec.annotation = "This is the annotation for this VM"

# CloneSpec
clonespec = vim.vm.CloneSpec()
clonespec.location = relospec
clonespec.powerOn = power_on
clonespec.config = configSpec

print ("cloning VM...")
task = template.Clone(folder=destfolder, name=vm_name, spec=clonespec)
wait_for_task(task)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `clonespec.customization` ([vim.vm.customization.Specification](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/vm/customization/Specification.rst)). You should be able to specify the hostname there somehow or other.

Oh, as far as I know VMware Tools must be installed for guest OS customization.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Here's an example of the customization spec in use to do what you're wanting, starting at line 190: https://gist.github.com/snobear/8788977